# Is there a better way of describing/etc. the "Logic" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I don't really have any concrete suggestions, but it seems that a lot of the questions where people not entirely familiar with the purpose of the subreddit who are asking general "philosophical questions" tend to use the 'logic' tag on their posts, perhaps not realizing that it has a very specific meaning in philosophy.

As someone who is here primarily *for* logic, this is a minor annoyance, especially when I'm getting email alerts for stuff that is essentially noise. Is there any way to improve this? Or should we just assume that these users are likely going to post off-topic questions that will be closed/removed anyway and so it isn't a problem?

Comment: Perhaps rename it to philosophical logic to emphasise the distinction?

Comment: @MoziburUllah but then a layperson still might think that it just means "argue this point philosophically"?

Answer (score 2):

The [tag wiki](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tags/logic/info) states:

> Logic is the study of formal systems of reasoning, especially of the deductive variety. It is one of the few fundamental philosophical subdisciplines, along with metaphysics, ontology and aesthetics. Logic has taken on considerable importance in recent mathematical developments, and one of the concerns of philosophy-of-mathematics involves the role, extent and conceptual architecture of various kinds of logical or formal axiomatic systems.

Now, I think this is a good scope for this tag, and I *think* you do too. So, if a question does *not* fit this description and yet it *is* tagged [logic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic), you are well invited to suggest an edit to remove that tag. Possibly, add a comment to explain your edit. This helps to educate fellow users. I have reviewed some suggested edits of yours, so you know how this works.

If you do *not* agree that the tag wiki provides a good scope definition, I'd like to challenge you to write a better one, and edit this meta question to ask if others would agree it would be better like that. It is possible to suggest tag wiki edits, but if you're fundamentally going to change the scope of our most-used tag, I suppose it would be a good idea to discuss that on meta first.

Comment: I agree that the current scope is fine insofar as it describes the topic area well. I was more thinking if there was a reasonable way that we could make new/unfamiliar users aware that it means something other than "I'm looking for a logical explanation of...". But I guess the problem with that idea is that if these users aren't reading the tag description before applying it, then it wouldn't matter even if we were to change it.